# Find equation of non-polynomial curve

Tags: integration, logarithms

I have manually created a set of data points in the x-y plane that approximate the curve of the integral of a certain trigonometric function.  What technique or branch of maths can I use to generate the actual equation of that curve, using only those data points?  (For purposes of this discussion, the actual curve is logarithmic, not polynomial, but assume that we do not know that in advance.)

Comment: Interpolation could do what you want, there are several flavors of that. Approximation by polynomial or spline or rational functions is popular.

Comment: This is in the branch called mathematical modeling and curve fitting.  Your application will tell you whether an exact fit or an approximate fit is useful.  Problems about evaluating the function in between your known data points are called *interpolation* while predicting function values beyond the range of known points is called *extrapolation*.